# X86 Assembly Converting lower-case to uppercase

Tags: assembly, x86

Implement the toUpper function that converts lower-case letters in a string
to upper-case. The function takes one parameter: char *string. string is a
char type pointer, which points to the beginning of the string. Because C-
style strings are terminated by a zero, we do not need to take the length of
the string as another parameter.

I need help getting started, I don't know what I am doing!!

```c
void toUpper(char *string) {
__asm{
        PUSH EAX
        PUSH EBX
        PUSH ECX
        PUSH EDX
        PUSH ESI
        PUSH EDI

        MOV EBX, string
        /* Your code begins below this line. */


        /* Your code ends above this line. */
        POP EDI
        POP ESI
        POP EDX
        POP ECX
        POP EBX
        POP EAX
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load each character into 8bit register (MOV AL,[EBX]), check if end-of-string is reached, decide whether it needs to be converted (compare AL with boundaries 'a'..'z') and move the corresponding uppercase letter back to [EBX] if yes. Then increment EBX and loop back.

```
ASCII code of uppercase letter 'A'..'Z'  is 0x41..0x5A
ASCII code of lowercase letter 'a'..'z'  is 0x61..0x7A
```

so the case can be changed either by subtracting 0x20 from lowercase letter, 
or by masking off the 5th bit (AND AL,0xDF).